# [React Native]How to realize Popup Dialog box in RN Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I would like to realize feature like AlertIOS but didn't find components on RN website or other open source components. Do we have to implement our own native module for this function? It's a quite common feature so I assume there will be some components available. Sorry if I missed any.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Modal component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html#content). In your case, using the one like in the UIExplorer with transparent will look just like the AlertIOS.